# unidata odbc sql syntax for date

Tags: sql, unidata

What is the sql syntax to filter by date Unidata ODBC, I'm doing this

```
select 
 *
from
      ACCOUNT_DATA
where 
      ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE >=  {d '2014-11-1'}
```

But is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how the date field is defined.

I.E.  The following works in the demo account at the SQL prompt

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE DATE_OUT = '04/25/94';

Note that the format is day/month/year,  this is how it is set in the dictionary.